# Odata db adapter for ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest, odata

> *I've developed a ZF based app that needs to access a remote database that I manage. I am considering REST as an option to publish data from the remote db and consume to the local ZF app. Digging the web I found that Odata is gaining  interest and acceptance so **my first question is:***

Is it worth the pain to use Odata to publish and consume?

Taking a look into the specs I found it heavy enough so a fair amount of effort will be needed to implement. Of course there are libs and examples but still it is not simple. Instead I may implement a simple protocol to publish and consume.

Concerning integration of the REST service into ZF I have ***a second question***:

Should I write a new  `Zend_DB_Adapter_Abstract` adapter for the Odata or my proprietary protocol?

Does anybody know of any similar effort (Odata or REST adapter for ZEND)?

Comment: From reading your question I'm guessing that your servers for DB and Application (ZF). Why not simply connect to the remote DB directly in your ZF application?